# How to filter by post-format in admin?

Tags: wp-admin, filters, post-formats

I need to filter my posts by Post-Formats in admin ?

How can I do that ?

For now, Wordpress allows to filter by Categories and Dates.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this plugin i cooked up:

```
<?php
! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) AND exit;
/**
 * Plugin Name: (#26032) WP_List_Table Post Format filter extension
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26032/how-to-filter-by-post-format-in-admin
 * Description: Filters the admin WP_List_Table by post format
 * Author:      Bainternet
 * Author URI: http://en.bainternet.info
 */


function wpse26032_admin_posts_filter( &$query )
{
    if ( 
        is_admin() 
        AND 'edit.php' === $GLOBALS['pagenow']
        AND isset( $_GET['p_format'] )
        AND '-1' != $_GET['p_format']
        )
    {
        $query->query_vars['tax_query'] = array( array(
             'taxonomy' => 'post_format'
            ,'field'    => 'ID'
            ,'terms'    => array( $_GET['p_format'] )
        ) );
    }
}
add_filter( 'parse_query', 'wpse26032_admin_posts_filter' );

function wpse26032_restrict_manage_posts_format()
{
    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
         'taxonomy'         => 'post_format'
        ,'hide_empty'       => 0
        ,'name'             => 'p_format'
        ,'show_option_none' => 'Select Post Format'
    ) );
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse26032_restrict_manage_posts_format' );
```

Comment: Yep ! Thanks ! It WORKS perfectly except when I choose no post-format, it returns me nothing. Example : One category + no post-format = NOTHING

Comment: Just a note, you can actually query directly for post formats by adding `&post_format=aside` as an example to the URL...However!!! .. it doesn't quite work properly and generates notices/warnings, which i can only assume is a bug as it also has other side-effects(you'll see what i mean if you test it).

Comment: @Steffi: sorry i  fixed it (I think) and updated the code.

Comment: Had a few problems getting the filter to work myself, you may be able to spot a fix in my code(one thing specifically had me going in circles for a while).. ;)

Comment: @t31os, fixed and tested, code updated.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the clean up. +1 and it works with 3.4.1 without a problem.

Comment: Just tested this out in WordPress 4.6.2 and works great!  Thanks for providing the logic!

Answer (score 2):

I was actually already working on a solution for you, just had to rewrite several parts of the code(because i based it off another plugin i wrote that does the same but for page templates on hierarchal types).

This is a little bigger than Bainternet's plugin, so by all means stick to his solution if you're happy with it(don't feel obligated to switch is all i'm saying), i'm going to post it up anyway, for the sake of anyone who may be interested. It'll work for any post type that supports post formats.

**Edit/Update:** *Decided i might aswell put the code into a proper plugin, also did the same for adding a page template filter to hierarchal post types(that support page templates). Linked below for anyone interested,*

- [Post Format Filter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-format-filter/)
- [Page Template Filter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-template-filter/)

Hope that's helpful.. :)

Comment: **NOTE:** If i missed/overlooked anything, drop a comment onto the answer.

Answer (score 1):

A little bugfix, to keep the dropdown selection to the actual post format, in the function **wpse26032_restrict_manage_posts_format** :

```
function wpse26032_restrict_manage_posts_format()
{

    $post_format_ID = ( isset( $_GET['p_format'] ) && $_GET['p_format'] != '' ) ? $_GET['p_format'] : -1;

    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
         'taxonomy'         => 'post_format'
        ,'hide_empty'       => 0
        ,'name'             => 'p_format'
        ,'show_option_none' => 'Select Post Format'
        ,'selected'         => $post_format_ID
    ) );
}
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', 'wpse26032_restrict_manage_posts_format' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Since WordPress 4.3, the function `column_title()` will include the post format as an icon next to the post title. Clicking this icon will automatically filter the current list to the selected post format.

The accepted answer(s) will continue to work, and display the dropdown, however, it can be simplified as we don't need to filter the query afterwards if we use the same query variables.

```
add_action( 'restrict_manage_posts', function( $post_type = "" ) {
    if ( in_array( $post_type, array( 'post' ) ) ) {
        wp_dropdown_categories( array(
            'taxonomy'          => 'post_format',
            'hide_empty'        => 0,
            'name'              => 'post_format', // Do not need to use a custom variable name.
            'show_option_all'   => 'Select Post Format', // Use 'show_option_all' instead of 'show_option_none' as the default choice.
            'value_field'       => 'slug',
        ) );
    }
} );
```

An alternative method is to display the post format as its own column. The following code will display a link which will filter the list, although I'm having issues making this column sortable, as WordPress doesn't include any tax queries when all formats are being shown.

```
// Add post format column.
add_action( 'manage_posts_columns', function( $columns ) {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( isset( $screen->post_type ) && in_array( $screen->post_type, array( 'post' ) ) ) {
        $columns['post_format'] = _( 'Post Format' );
    }
    return $columns;
} );

// Output post format in column.
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , function( $column, $post_id ) {
    switch( $column ) {
        case 'post_format':
            $format = get_post_format( $post_id ) ?: 'standard';
            echo sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                add_query_arg( array( 'post_format' => $format ) ),
                __( ucfirst( $format ) ) );
            break;
    }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Both the short version of the format, as provided by `get_post_format()`, and the long version output by `wp_dropdown_categories()`, appear to work in the same fashion when filtering posts.

**EDIT:** `get_post_format` will return false if there is an error or no format is selected. In this case it should be safe to assume 'standard' as the selected format. I've included a fallback to 'standard' when `get_post_format()` returns false.

Comment: `get_post_format()` returns blank when the default 'Standard' post format is selected. You may way to consider adding a check after that function so that the column will show 'Standard' where applicable.
`if ( empty( $format ) ) {
 $format = 'standard';
}`